# Read multiple csv files within a function

Tags: r, function, csv

I'm trying to read multiple .csv files using a function and have found lots of similar questions/answers but none seem to address my specific issue.

The following code works fine

```
id=3:5

selected_files=list.files()[id]

for(i in 1:length(id)){
assign(selected_files[i], read.csv(selected_files[i]))
}
```

However, when putting this code inside a function the code runs but no files are read in

```
readfiles=function(id){
selected_files=list.files()[id]
for(i in 1:length(id)){
assign(selected_files[i], read.csv(selected_files[i]))
 }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Use `lapply(selected_files, read.csv)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your dataframes are being set within the the function environment, not the global environment. Change your `assign()` to 
`assign(selected_files[i], read.csv(selected_files[i]), envir = .GlobalEnv)`